# «Костюм цвета сомо» — какой он?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, устаревшие-слова

[В балетном отделении концерта в красносельском театре] *я танцевала польку из «Талисмана». Костюм у меня был **цвета сомо** и мне к лицу*.
(Так — в газетном варианте. А. Добровольский. [Интимный дневник Матильды Кшесинской](http://www.mk.ru/social/2017/03/19/dnevnik-matildy-kshesinskoy-o-romane-s-cesarevichem-nikolaem-publikuetsya-vpervye.html))

Впервые в жизни встречаюсь с таким обозначением — названием, описанием, характеристикой — цвета.

А каков он, этот цвет — **сомо**? Где еще был озвучен?

Буду благодарна за информацию, разъяснения и, если возможно, примеры.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цвет, описанный г-ном Морковкиным, в быту назывался по-разному: само, сомо и сомон, цвет сёмги, сёмужный, лососёвый и просто сомоновый - от первоисточника saumon (сёмга). Цвет оказался французом.

> Лососевый цвет был популярен в конце XIX века и страшно популярен в
>   50-е годы XX века. Впрочем, в то время с ним успешно соревновался
>   ядреный пинк (англ. pink - розовый), введенный в моду Эльзой
>   Скьяпарелли, вечной соперницей Шанель. XX век вообще оказался
>   поклонником розового. Хотя в интерьере с сомоном работать очень
>   трудно. Дэвид Хикс называл этот цвет в ряду пяти самых дисгармоничных
>   оттенков.

В нашем доме сомоном считали телесный, цвет нежного загара. )))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В литературе упоминается нередко, но и не на каждом шагу...

---

**[Само-сомо-сомон...](https://www.livemaster.ru/topic/1319447-samo-somo-somon?)**

...А вот что писали в конце 1820-х годов в периодической печати:

> «У модисток явился новый цвет, называемый цвет семги» («Московский
>   телеграф», 1829, № 7, с. 357).

Так как разделы моды печатались в те годы на русском и французском языках, то во французском варианте текста можно прочесть: «une couleur nouvelle porte le nom de saumon». Время от времени цвет само забывали, но он вновь входил в моду:

> «Однажды к нам на званый вечер явилась Софья Сергеевна Кедрова,
>   красивая барышня из богатой семьи, жгучая брюнетка. На ней было пышное
>   платье из тяжелой шелковой ткани цвета saumon — изжелта-розовой
>   лососины, модного в начале 1890-х годов. На проймах лифа при бальном
>   декольте, трепетали две маленькие черные птички, выписанные из Парижа.
>
> Выбор материи, цвет сомон и фасон с парижскими птичками — все
>   принадлежало вкусу знаменитой m-me Минангуа, у которой шила сама
>   Ермолова, бывшая тогда в зените своей славы... Один отец находил, что 
>   это туалет для театральной сцены, а не для вечера в семейном доме.
>   "Все кричит на этой барышне: и цвет сОмон кричит еще больше этих
>   птиц"» (Дурылин С. Н., В своем углу, М., 1991, с. 185).

[Русское название цвета — цвет семги или лососины](http://cult-and-art.net/society/110131-chem_cvet_byodra_ispugannoj_nimfy_otlichaetsja_ot_cveta_adskogo_plameni__ili_kakie_byvajut_cveta__chast_9) — почти не встречается в современной литературной речи, а вот различные варианты французского saumon дошли до наших дней. Обычно под ним подразумевают грязновато-розовый цвет.

---

> «Анна Ивановна в платье цвета couleur saumon; шея и плечи открыты,
>   бриллиантовые серьги в три подвески, большой букет из фарфоровых
>   цветов на корсаже» (Рассказы бабушки, Из воспоминаний пяти поколений,
>   записанные и собранные ее внуком Д. Благово, М., 1989, с. 62).
>
> ---
>
> Монахов частенько упрекали за пристрастие к изысканным сортам рыбы,
>   обыгрывая сходство слов "царь Соломон" и "сёмга" ("сомон" —
>   по-французски). О таких монахах-лакомках говорили:
>
> **Толкует много о сомоне,**
>
> **А надо бы о Соломоне.**

(Монастырские нравы изучать **[ТУТЪ](http://wod.su/dark_ages/history/book/life_monk/02)**.)

**[САМО](http://folk-costume.com/samo/)**

...Не такой агрессивный, как оранжевый, не столь девичий, как розовый, цвет «само» относится к любимым у тех, кто делает ставку на необычность и женственность. Идеален в союзе с серебряными дополнениями.

> «Императрица подарила мне с барского плеча платье очень тонкое, цвета saumon, украшенное шелковыми лилиями. Так как всегда нужно было 36 тысяч туалетов, Мария Савельевна вечно придумывала что-нибудь новое; она отделала нежный цвет saumon ярко-красным, а корсаж украсила черной бахромой» (А. О. Смирнова-Россет. Автобиографические записки. 1870—82).
>
> ---
>
> «– Тебе нравится мое платье? Я вчера его купила. Госпожа Фавори была
>   так великодушна. – Очаровательно. Но почему розовое? Ярко-розовый
>   совсем не сочетается с цветом «сомон» моего галстука. – Никто не
>   обратит на это внимания. Тем более в такую рань. Пожалуйста,
>   поторопись» (Дафна Дюморье. Мери Энн).
>
> ---
>
> Почему вам понравился цвет "saumon"? - передразнила она продавца. Цвет
>   сёмги. Дохлой рыбы, может, протухшей (Р. Шенталь. Виктор Стойницкий).
>
> ---
>
> Встречи <...> в квартире ее мужа, с высокими комнатами, уставленными
>   старой прадедовой мебелью, в будуаре Валентины Артемьевны, цвета
>   saumon (А. Селиванов. Осенние мухи).

Из [Исторического словаря галлицизмов русского языка](http://www.terminy.info/russian-language/historical-dictionary-of-russian-language-gallicisms/somo) - вопрос:

*Слегка либеральный с антисемитским оттенком?*

> Против нас оказалась бы вся эта умеренно-либеральная Москва, все эти
>   красноречивые господа с убеждениями цвета saumon, как выражается
>   братец мой Антон Валерьянович (Амфитеатров. Восьмидесятники. 1904).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Роза — оттенка сомон.](http://ocvete.ru/oranzhevyj-cvet/cvet-samo.html)

---

Синонимы:
оранжево-розовый, розовато-желтый, розово-желтый.

---

Да, "костюм" из вопроса я как-то упустила... вуаля!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Ответ на комментарий об ударении в цитате - специально для Артёма: возможно, это типо речевой характеристики персонажа? Я и книгу нашла с проставленными ударениями (дважды):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Avanesova Благодарю Вас за удачную корректуру вопроса и за не менее удачный ответ.

Comment: Риммочка! Пошто по хвамилии обзываетесь - што я Вам плохого сделала?! О_о Благодарят тута не так, а: лайкают ответ (верхний треугольничек слева, дизлайкают нижний), а под всеми этими треугольничками есть галочка, видная исключительно вопрошателю: ею можно одарить только один ответ из поступивших, что означает "ответ помог!"

Comment: Извините, ТАК получилось , без имени,  - никоим образом не хотела Вас обидеть! Зато, следуя Вашему примеру,  изменила ссылки в "щиплет".  Правильно ли?

Comment: А я ещё красивше это "щипит" сделала... )))

Comment: Отличный ответ! Галин, а почему у вас в цитате тут ударение на первый слог: *Все кричит на этой барышне: и цвет сОмон кричит еще больше этих птиц*? Ответьте через собачку, пожалуйста, чтобы я уведомление получил.

Comment: Тёмыч, и так получишь. Я в ответ добавила скрин из книжки https://imwerden.de/pdf/durylin_v_svoem_uglu_1991__ocr.pdf - *Дурылин С. Н.  В своем углу: Из старых тетрадей.*

Comment: Вот не получил, кстати!) Непонятно, почему на первый слог ударение при том, что это заимствование из французского.

Comment: Это сознательно проставленное ударение. С вопросами - к г-ну Дурылину.

Answer (score 2):

"Цвет лосося".
Светло-розовый с примесью оранжевого, желтого, пастельного.
Сомо - лосось.

http://flashdecor.livejournal.com/55369.html

Comment: Душевная ссылка. Засмотрелась!