# Где найти полный список реальных названий цветов на русском языке?

Tags: лексика, лексикография

Занимаюсь аспектным анализом отзывов на русском, и меня интересуют все упоминания цвета товара, я пользовался стандартным списком с Википедии, но там только официальные названия, и понял, что пропускаю много интересного среди нетипичных названий, типа "розоватый", "пастельный", "мышиный" и т.п. Может, есть какие-то рекомендации где достать более полный открытый список?

Answer (score 3):

Можно посмотреть здесь: ализариновый, сангрия, шокирующий розовый...
[26 оттенков красного цвета и их цветовые координаты](https://sveres.ru/articles/tsvetovedenie/26-ottenkov-krasnogo-tsveta-i-ikh-tsvetovye-koordinaty.html)

Можно здесь: цвет Бискайского залива, средневековый синий, цвет еловой тени, морской пены, ледяной зеленый, цвет листа водяной лилии, цвет северного сияния, цвет кукурузной шелухи, цвет закатного золота, одуванчиковый, цвет ежевичного вина, рассветный фиолетовый, цвет затмения, цвет пыльной лаванды, оттенок золотого самородка, фламинговый, дынный, глиняный, цвет заката в каньоне...
[Оттенки синего. Таблица цветов](https://lookcolor.ru/news/sinie-cveta/)
[Оттенки зеленого. Таблица цветов](https://lookcolor.ru/news/zelenye-cveta/)
[Оттенки желтого. Таблица цветов](https://lookcolor.ru/zheltyj/zheltye-cveta/)
[Оттенки фиолетового. Таблица цветов](https://lookcolor.ru/news/fioletovye-cveta/)
[Оттенки оранжевого](https://lookcolor.ru/news/oranzhevye-cveta/)

P. S. Когда-то я задавала схожий вопрос: [«Костюм цвета сомо» — какой он?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430956/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BC-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BD)
Ответ — блеск, лучше не бывает!